# How to handle both the KeyDown and KeyUp events in a Silverlight 3 TextBox

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am attaching handlers to the KeyDown and KeyUp events of a Silverlight 3 TextBox as so:

```
_masterTextBox.KeyDown += (s, args) =>
{
     CheckForUserEnteredText(MasterTextBox.Text);
     args.Handled = false;
};

_masterTextBox.KeyUp += (s, args) => { UpdateText(MasterTextBox.Text); };
```

When I comment out the KeyDown handler, then the KeyUp will trap the event, otherwise, only the KeyDown handler is triggered.

Can someone explain why the KeyUp event handler is not firing after the KeyDown handler does?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look inside your `CheckForUserEnteredText` function.  Certainly there is no reason from the posted code alone for KeyUp not to fire and it does in my testing.

Perhaps `CheckForUserEnteredText` does something to prevent it? You seem to have both a public field/property called `MasterTextBox` and one called `_masterTextBox`, do you need both? Could it be the KeyUp is firing but UpdateText isn't doing what you expect?  The list could go on, the bottom line is there isn't a problem with the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was that I was setting a break point in the keydown method.  Apparently, when you set a break point, it misses the keyup event.